# How to target specific element with DynamicComponentLoader?

Tags: angular

### Background

I have a data that represent list of folders and categories of documents; I get it from our information management software through web interface. From that raw list where each item has `ParentFolderNo` I've created an object with `children: any[]` property - basically now I have nested list of items; something like this:

```
{
  id: 123,
  Guid: "8dcaae38-4dcc-48f7-bd91-c8b0cb725890"
  children: [
    {
      id: 234,
      Guid: "...."
    },
    {
      id: 345,
      Guid: "...."
      children: [...]
    }
  ]
}
```

### Implementation

There are many more objects there, some have it's own children, some don't, but each is unique and has a unique `Guid`. From this object I need to create UI element that lets user select specific folder or category and limit the search. You can think of it as selectable breadcrumbs. I've created component that uses `DynamicComponentLoader` to display specific 'tree' of this data:

```
@Component({
  host: { "[attr.id]": "category.Guid" },
  selector: 'category-group',
  template: `
    <ul class="category__group">
      <li>
        <a (click)="select()">All Categories</a>
      </li>
      <li [class.selected]="child.selected" *ngFor="#child of category.children">
        <a *ngIf="!child.selected" (click)="select(child)">{{ child.Name }}</a>
        <b *ngIf="child.selected">{{ child.Name }}</b>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
})
class Category {
  public category: any;

  select(theCategory: any) {
    this.category.children.map(subcategory => subcategory.selected = false);
    if (theCategory) {
      theCategory.selected = true;
      // pass theCategory to CategorySelectComponent
      // to create new category-group... this works.
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'category-select',
  template: `
    <b>Root</b> 
    <div #root></div>
  `,
})
export class CategorySelectComponent {
  @Input() root: any;

  constructor(
    private _dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, 
    private _eref: ElementRef, 
    private _inj: Injector
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() { this.create(this.root); }

  create(parent: any) {
    if (!parent.children) return;
    this._dcl
      .loadIntoLocation(Category, this._eref, 'root')
      .then(ref => ref.instance.category = parent)
  }
}
```

This works, but there's a flaw - it just adds new `<category-group>`. When I select different child I need to replace category-groups 'below' it. So:

#### Is there a way to replace a component with DynamicComponentLoader?

```
  create(parent: any) {
    if (!parent.children) return;
    // Guid":"8dcaae38-4dcc-48f7-bd91-c8b0cb725890"
    this._dcl
      .loadIntoLocation(Category, this._eref, 'root')
      .then(ref => ref.instance.category = parent)
  }
```

What can I do with this `create()` function to get the functionality I need? How can I use element with `id="8dcaae38-4dcc-48f7-bd91-c8b0cb725890"` in `_dcl`? I tried [other methods](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html) but didn't manage to make this work...

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you remove the existing one and add the new one? Do you have a plnkr with your working approach so far?

Comment: No plunkr yet, didn't have time to isolate this, too many dependencies (; As for removing... I didn't try yet. In DOM they are siblings when I use `loadIntoLocation()`, not sure yet if I should remove them from DOM directly, there could be side effects when I'm generating list of categories to search... didn't get that far (;

Comment: Now that I think about it, removing existing ones could be the right approach.  I can filter the list by `selected` property...

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually having the same problem (I'm new in Angular2), but basically if you use `loadIntoLocation()` method it won't replace any existing template. But if you use `loadAsRoot()` it will (taking into account you point to the same selector. For example:

> ```
> this._dynamicComponentLoader.loadAsRoot(ComponentA, '#container', this._injector)
>                 .then((res) => {
>                     res.instance["label"] = "text1";
>                     compRef.location.internalElement.parentView.changeDetector.ref.detectChanges();
>                 });
> ```

And the next time you want to replace the content of the ComponentA for other template (let's say, to be original, ComponentB):

> ```
> this._dynamicComponentLoader.loadAsRoot(ComponentB, '#container', this._injector)
>                 .then((res) => {
>                     res.instance["label"] = "text2";
>                     compRef.location.internalElement.parentView.changeDetector.ref.detectChanges();
>                 });
> ```

You see that there is a strange line here:

> compRef.location.internalElement.parentView.changeDetector.ref.detectChanges();

That line is needed if you want to inform your components to listen for changes in their attributes when using `loadAsRoot()` method as you can see here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6223#issuecomment-193895253

Hope it helps.